# Graphic being cropped by EPS artboard when exported from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, eps

I've got a graphic in Illustrator that I want to export as an .EPS file.

But when I export it, it clips the bottom of the graphic (I've attached a screenshot below); you can't see it unless super zoomed in, but it basically removes the very bottom of any text that sits below the line like capital S and G.

I've added 10% size the artboard in Illustrator but to not avail. Apart from adding a white/clear object behind the logo, which feels like a work around, is there a proper way to fix this issue?

I've come across this issue before when exporting PNG files and in that case the solution is to make the artboard slightly bigger/align the graphic to the pixel grid, but don't see why I'm having the issue with an EPS image as it's a vector file.

[image: screenshot of issue in preview and illustrator]

I'm running Illustrator 2020 on a Mac running OSx 10.13.16

Comment: When you save the eps, have you tried checking the "use artboards" option?  I don't use a Mac, but [it looks like this](https://imgur.com/a/CxHr8nP) in Windows.

Comment: @BillyKerr thanks that works ! I presumed that it was already doing that as that was the only item in the whole file, but seems it wasnt